# Azure Event Hub Integration test

Tags: azure, integration-testing, azure-eventhub, akka-stream

I have written some code to push and pull data from Azure Event Hub. Searching through the internet couldn't find me any example of how to do the integration testing. In the past I was able to use [testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/) for pulsar and mqtt integration testing but couldn't find anything for Azure Event Hub. Test containers does have something called cosmodb which doesn't seem like the right thing. Would appreciate if anyone has any pointer.

Comment: There are no emulators or containerized versions of Event Hubs, currently.   The integration tests will need to use live Azure resources.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I read that using Biceps we can do integration testing by kind of creating an environment, do the testing against it and then tear it down. Does sound familiar? Do you have any pointers in that regard?

Comment: Bicep files just specify a set of Azure resources for deployment.  There's nothing magic about them for automation.   The best example of bootstrapping an environment for a test run that I can provide is the infrastructure used by the SDK, which attaches to an existing namespace and then dynamically creates a transient Event Hub per test.  https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/main/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Shared/src/Testing

Comment: Thanks for providing the link. Will see more into it.